# iOS VOIP call does not work in background

Tags: ios, iphone, pjsip

We are using Pjsip in TCP mode and already configured keep alive. Application running smoothly in background But after some time when App is trying to re register with SIP server registration message has been sent and app is not getting response,App is getting stuck at the time and then it won't work any more in background. After killing it works OK. can you advise what we are missing ?

Some time its work for 3-4 hours and some time it stop even in 5 minutes :(

Running This code when app is background :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { 

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [application setKeepAliveTimeout:KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL handler: ^{ 
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
} 

- (void)keepAlive {

    int i;

    if (!pj_thread_is_registered()) {
        pj_thread_register("ipjsua", a_thread_desc, &a_thread);
    }

    /* Since iOS requires that the minimum keep alive interval is 600s,
     * application needs to make sure that the account's registration
     * timeout is long enough.
     */

    for (i = 0; i < (int)pjsua_acc_get_count(); ++i) {
        if (pjsua_acc_is_valid(i)) {
            pjsua_acc_set_registration(i, PJ_TRUE);
        }
    }

    pj_thread_sleep(15000);

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: @neeku, Pls revisit the post I edited just now with require information